# RockMongo fatal error

Tags: php, mongodb, php-mongodb

I have installed rockmongo in my ubuntu from this [site](http://rockmongo.com/downloads).When I tried to open the rockmongo from browser it showing fatal error as like mentioned below.

Error:

```
Fatal error: ini_set(): To prevent data corruption, you are not allowed to turn on the mongo.native_long setting on 32-bit platforms in Unknown on line 0
```

How can i resolve this issue,can anyone give me a solution for this issue.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

native_long support for 32-bits has been (quite logically) [removed](https://github.com/mongodb/mongo-php-driver/commit/374d8048d3d512057ade23a7538d5f4bb2a7fdd1) from the mongo driver. . RockMongo uses `ini_set("mongo.native_long", 1);` in its index.php. As a quick fix, comment this line out.

Comment: Thank you Georg,I made a quick fix.

Answer (score 4):

The quick fix is [here](https://github.com/ivanmisic/Yii-MongoDB-Driver/commit/dda84ae81948454d357986dda7679935751a7d36), in `index.php` replace the ini_set line :

```
ini_set("mongo.native_long", 1);
```

with:

```
ini_set('mongo.native_long', strlen(decbin(~0)) == 32 ? 0 : 1);
```

Or just remove it, the default value is 1 anyway

Answer (score 1):

In my configuration

> Windows 7, Apache 2, PHP 5.5 [API220121212,TS,VC11], Mongo 2.6, Mongo PHP extension 1.5.7

only the **combination** of

```
ini_set("mongo.native_long", 0);
ini_set("mongo.long_as_object", 1);
```

helped to recover from the "*Cannot natively represent the long 9223372036854775807 on this platform*" error.